# Delphi couldn't build packages with Output directory

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, package, delphi-2007

I had Delphi 2010, but for some reasons I had to uninstall it, then install Delphi 2007.

After that I had to build some packages, that end up with these errors, knowing that on my pc at work they build without errors.

This error only occurs when I'm providing an Output Directory for the project to be built in.

These are the errors:
[image]

Would the problem be because of Delphi's version?

Comment: i can only share my expirence and let you know you entered a package hell. if you can go to the unicode version of delphi 2010, it would be easier, since the more advance the delphu version after 2005, the better, for pacakge.  if you insists on going with delphi 2007, i would recomand trying to use automation tools such as "delphi Pi" or "Multi-installer" if you would like i could explain more about them.

Comment: Well I need 2007, because @ work we use it, and I need to take work home with me, and I don't guess we should transfer the whole project to 2010. If you can explain more I will be thankful.

Comment: delhpi pi is a tool that was created by one of stack over flow user. its very easy to use, and very fast to compile, you choose the folder where all the dpk are at (or at sub folders) and the complier version. then you just pick which to compilem and it does some magic, works a couple of times, not always. multi installer is another tool, however you need effort to use, you need to write a setup.ini file to compile you packages. but it gives an atvatage that you have a "script" to run the packages install again , and again. start with delphi pi, on google code. then go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved. It was due  to an environment variable called PLATFORM.

You can see that this is conditional on PLATFORM being set to AnyCPU. If you have PLATFORM set to anything other than AnyCPU the condition will not be met and the Output path will not be set.

You can override environment variables in the IDE via the following steps:

Choose Tools | Options.
In the resulting dialog box, select Environment Variables node in the tree.
Locate PLATFORM.
Click on the Add Override… button.
In the Variable Value field, type AnyCPU.
Click OK in both dialogs and restart the IDE.
The output path will now be respected.